# What is the difference between "App Store" and "App Store Connect"

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, apple-store

I keep reading documentation on the process of creating an app for the 'app store' where it references `app store connect` and `app store` seemingly interchangeably. Apple is normally very deliberate and specific in documentation, are they the same or is there a difference I haven't picked up on?

example [`> Upload your app binary files with the Transporter app`]:
"The Transporter app for macOS is a simple and easy way to upload an app to App Store Connect for distribution on the App Store." (https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Store Connect is the developer only service, native and web app suite that connects you to the App Store and your customers.

On iOS and iPadOS each has its own app to help you keep things straight.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app-store-connect/id1234793120